# SQL Next/previous Assoc

Tags: php, sql, mysql

So, I am writing a PHP script that needs to get the next assoc in the SQL Query, But It seems like I am writing lots of code for something that is probably in MySQL somewhere, I tryed google but no luck.

Basically what I am doing is grabbing for a DB using this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM challenges WHERE subcat='%s' ORDER BY points, id ASC;
```

I am able to grab that value but I have a "next" button and Previous button I want to implement. I just do not know how in SQL I can do that instead of writing 15 lines of php to solve this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into LIMIT, you can specify a "start" and an "offset" and use them to paginate. Actually, search for "Pagination" for more information.

Comment: Only bad thing about that is all I know is the id of the current challenge, Not where it was located in that array.

Comment: you'd not need its position.. just 1 variable which holds the pagenumber, and increments by 10 or whatever on clicking next.. 
please take a look at LIMIT in this and do yourself a favour: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

Google for keyword "pagination mysql php". You'd get a lot of tutorials teaching you how to do it...

All you need is *limit* keyword from mysql

[ I am assuming you are asking about pagination ]